# Taking data from multiline textbox and utilising the data submitted PHP

Tags: php

Trying to understand how I can take multi-line textbox data and then utilise it using PHP.

Within the textbox I want users to be able to write down the format "Website,URL" per line and then generate as a link.

A user would post multiple lines of text:

E.g

Microsoft,https://microsoft.com

Stackoverflow,https://stackoverflow.com

I understand that I would need to use the php explode to break down the line into an array but how can I seperate the data from within that array and then utilise each point of data in a list format? I've confused myself writing this, hoping someone can help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Given this :
`Microsoft,https://microsoft.com  Stackoverflow,https://stackoverflow.com`

Expected to got this :

```
array(
'Microsoft' => 'https://microsoft.com',
'Stackoverflow' => 'https://stackoverflow.com'
)
```

**Code**

```
$data = "Microsoft,https://microsoft.com 
Stackoverflow,https://stackoverflow.com";
$result = array();
foreach(explode(' ', $data) as $values){
    $key_value = explode(",", $values);
    if (isset($key_value[0]) && isset($key_value[1]))
        $result[$key_value[0]] = $key_value[1]; // Construct array with meaningful key
}

var_dump($result);
```

**Result**

```
array(2) { ["Microsoft"]=> string(21) "https://microsoft.com" [" Stackoverflow"]=> string(25) "https://stackoverflow.com" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just to run through we could break it down like this to achieve a looped link result right ?

`<?php

 $data = "Microsoft,https://microsoft.com 
Stackoverflow,https://stackoverflow.com";
$result = array();
foreach(explode(' ', $data) as $values){
    $key_value = explode(",", $values);
    echo "<a href='".$key_value[1]."'>".$key_value[0]."</a>";
}
`

Comment: Yes it'll work as you do. But I personnaly prefer to keep data processing and data view separated. I recommend you to read about MVC pattern (wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller)

Comment: Even though this code will work perfectly, this is never a good idea to have HTML element inside a PHP script.